# How to create a single node with relationships to all nodes matching a query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm trying to create a set of queries which will do the following given a list of nodes:

1. If there is a node which has relationships to all the nodes in the list, return that node
2. If there is *not* such a node, create a node and relationships to each node in the list

My first attempt was with these two queries:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id IN {userIds} 
WITH collect(u) as users
MATCH (conversation:Conversation) 
WHERE ALL(u in users WHERE (u)-->(conversation)) 
RETURN conversation

MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN {userIds} 
MERGE (conversation:Conversation {id: {conversationId}}) 
WITH conversation 
MERGE (user)-[:In]->(conversation) 
RETURN conversation
```

But the result is that one conversation node is created for *each* user node, and what I want is one conversation node which is connected to *all* user nodes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `WITH` clause, you need to pass *user*:

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN {userIds} 
MERGE (conversation:Conversation {id: {conversationId}}) 
WITH conversation, user 
MERGE (user)-[:In]->(conversation) 
RETURN conversation
```